# tcolorbox: problem with "colbacklower" and "text outside listing"

Tags: tcolorbox

According to `tcolorbox` documentation

[image]

and I would like to know which `lower part options` are available to change lower part aspect.

May be I misunderstand this text, but I would like to obtain something like
this:

[image]

using `listing outside text` but I only get

[image]

even with `colbacklower=red!30` option. With `listing side text` and `bicolor` skin, `colbacklower` works as expected: text (lower) part has a colored background

[image]

So the question is: is it possible to define a background color and frame for `text` parts when using `listing outside text` or `text outside listing`?

The code used for previous examples was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height]
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{text only, colback=red!30}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcblisting}{bicolor, listing side text, colbacklower=red!30}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{bicolor, listing outside text, colbacklower=red!30}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the documentation text for `listings outside text` is a copy - and - paste and is meant for `listing side text` actually only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, *formatted with all lower part options* should better be written *formatted with most lower part options*, because the outside text is put into a normal minipage. I think, adapting this for two `tcolorbox`es side by side is complicated (if possible at all). For this, we would need some not existing option like `listing outside boxed text` with some additional code.

Nevertheless, the desired output can be generated by setting up some new environment, e.g. `myspecial`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myspecial}[1]{%
  \begingroup\tcbwritetemp}%
{\endtcbwritetemp\endgroup%
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height,#1]%
    \tcbitem[]\tcbusetemplisting%
    \tcbitem[colback=red!30]\tcbusetemp%
  \end{tcbitemize}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myspecial}{}
An equation:
\[
  1 + 1 = 2
\]
\end{myspecial}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]